# Downloading jasper files in grails

Tags: grails, download

I have the folowing code:

```
response.contentType = "application/octet-stream"
response.setContentLength(templateFile.bytes.length)
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${fileName}")
IOUtils.copy(templateFile,response.outputStream)
```

Where templateFile is Jasper Report template(*.jrxml). 
And I always get net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.
For the different file types this code works fine.

Also i tried with content type 'text/xml' but result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after calling flush() on outputStream. Operator << do this implicitly while IOUtils.copy not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set length of your data using `response.setContentLength()`. Also, you can debug to see if the bytes of your file are in the `response.outputStream`.

Here's the snippet that work for me:

```
byte[] bytes = getBytesOfFile()
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
response.setContentLength(bytes.length)
response.outputStream << bytes
```

Comment: ContentLength is set and the bytes are in outputStream but browser still gets ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error.

Comment: hmm maybe the file is corrupted? Can you open this in the system with no errors?

Comment: File is valid. As I see - GrailsDispatcherServlet performs 'render' on ModelAndView returned from the controller and outputStream becomes empty. Looks like I should dig into this method.

Comment: Do you have anything after `IOUtils.copy()`?